# How to decide how PhpStorm formats comments in TWIG code?

Tags: ide, twig, phpstorm, comments, jetbrains-ide

I recently lost my PhpStorm settings and am unable to recover them. Since this PhpStorm seems to format my code differently when I try turn a line into a comment. I do so by pressing : `ctrl + /`.

I have googled about the issue (regarding Twig templates) And unfortunately I haven't found an answer.

Current situation:

```php
{% for comment in phpstorm %}
    {% if comment|length %}
{#        {{ "now"|date("m/d/Y") }}#}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Expected result:

```php
{% for comment in phpstorm %}
    {% if comment|length %}
        {# {{ "now"|date("m/d/Y") }} #}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

As you can see the in my current situation the comment doesn't respect it's current situation and it doesn't place a space after and before the  comment tags.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't change anything in the config ? Because I don't have this behaviour when I apply line comment

Comment: Could it be you previously used `[tab]` as tabing character and now you're using 4 `[spaces] `?

Comment: Just tried the same on a fresh new installation, the result is the same as expected. Did you try to reset settings to default in "Editor | Code Style | Twig"?

Comment: @user10550971 I did reset my settings, I even reinstalled and I still face the same problem.

Comment: @DarkBee This is not the case. Double checked.

Comment: @gogaz Yes, I even reinstalled the IDE, with deleting the previous settings. My problem remains.

Comment: I found no option able to configure this behaviour, you should try upgrading your version or contact the official support

Answer (score 0):

Go to plugins install **symfony** plugin and **php annotation**

After install go preferences->Languages & Frameworks -> Symfony and in top enable the plugin symfony .

After that go to File->Invalid Caches / Restart

I hope  it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

In your settings go to: **Editor** > **Code Style** > **HTML** then to tab **Code Generation** and *uncheck* "Line comment at first column".

(You may want to do the same for other languages like PHP).

[image: Settings]